# Rails - Iterating through records witin a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a method that just iterates through various models, printing out the model attributes:

```
def self.get_attributes(options = {})
  options[:model_name].find(:all, :conditions => {:generated_at => options[:start_date]..options[:end_date]}).each do |p|
  puts p.options[:col_name]
end
```

to call the method:

```
start_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:start_date], '%m/%d/%Y').beginning_of_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
end_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:end_date], '%m/%d/%Y').end_of_day.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
get_attributes({:model_name =>  Revenue, :col_name => "revenue",  :start_date => start_date, :end_date => end_date})
```

I have tried passing in the column name as a string and variable. When passed as a variable I get an `undefined variable` exception. As is above, I get an `undefined method 'col_name'` exception. How can I interpolate the column name within the above method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would represent the column/method name as a symbol (e.g. `:revenue`) and invoke it with `__send__` as in:

```
p.__send__(options[:col_name])
```